# ReactiveUI: R/W properties vs. Output Properties

Tags: c#, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a "Close" button and an [Expander](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander(v=vs.110).aspx) linked in my MVVM view like so:

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.CloseResults, v => v.CloseButton);
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.HasExecuted, v => v.Panel.IsExpanded);
```

If the user clicks on the button, the expander should be collapsed. In the view model, I have a ReactiveCommand that should take care of this:

```
public ReactiveCommand<object> CloseResults { get; protected set; } =
   ReactiveCommand.Create();
```

In the view model, `HasExecuted` is an Output Property that is supposed to expand/collapse the expander depending on its value:

```
private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _hasExecuted;
public bool HasExecuted => _hasExecuted.Value;
```

So to hook up the command with the button, I'm binding `HasExecuted` to the command like so:

```
CloseResults.Select(_ => false).ToProperty(this, vm => vm.HasExecuted, out _hasExecuted);
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. However, if I use a read-write property instead and hook it up like this:

```
CloseResults.Subscribe(_ => { HasExecuted = false; });
```

it works perfectly. Can anyone explain why the Output Property doesn't work in this case? Isn't the `ToProperty` extension supposed to subscribe to the `IOberservable<bool>` that `Select(_ => false)` is returning?

I'm still in the middle of getting the hang of all this, so there's probably something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Seems to me that HasExecuted observable will always be false. Also you can't set it, because it's readonly.

Comment: Well, `HasExecuted` is previously set to true, that's what makes the panel expanded in the first place. And the read-only member is the `ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool>`, not the bool itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output properties are meant to reflect the state of other properties or observables. It's basically a little formula you write that gives a property as an output. You aren't meant to set them directly. See [the docs for this](http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/stable/basics/to-property/).

**CloseResults.Select(_ => false)**.ToProperty(this, vm => vm.HasExecuted, out _hasExecuted);

^ This is saying "No matter what CloseResults it giving as an output, return an Observable that always returns false"

CloseResults.Select(_ => false).**ToProperty(this, vm => vm.HasExecuted, out _hasExecuted);**

^ This is saying "Take that always-false Observable and turn it into the HasExecuted output property."

Your read/write property is more suited to what you're trying to do here.